# Bash: if condition to check if actual date exists as string in file?

Tags: bash

In a file i have a string like this which is the date of today

```
Sa 4. Dez
```

Date format is like this

```
stringtoday=`date +%Y-%m`
```

now i wanna use a if condition to check if the date of today exists in this file and if that's the case i want stop the bash script. if the date is not in this file. the script should run.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=$(date +%Y-%m)

if grep "$DATE" file >/dev/null; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

where `file` is the name of your file should work. It basically uses `grep` to search for the value of `$DATE` in file, and branches depending on whether it was found or not (the exit codes of `grep` indicate this, see `man grep` "EXIT STATUS" for more information). You can use `if grep …; then exit 0; fi` to exit the script if the text is found to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: `man grep`. See what `-q` does.